Are there some differences from the previous election?
It was recently announced that there is going to be moderator election soon: Upcoming Moderator Election.
In January 2024 one of the CMs made this post: What would you like to change about the moderator election process? Basically an announcement that some changes might be coming and a request for feedback.

Should we expect some changes compared to previous election on the site?
If there were some changes, did some sites already hold election after these changes? (The linked post lists April as the date for testing the election on some sites and May as the date for "MSE update & next steps".)

For example, Bicycles had election in May and June. So did Blender.
I browsed their meta sites a little, but I did not find some info about changes in the election process.

I have pinged SpencerG, the community moderator responsible for running the current election.  I do not believe that any changes have been made since January, but he will, hopefully, be able to shed more light.

Elections network-wide are still running as they have been in the past. The election system has not changed from how it has been run in the last few years.

Thanks for the answer! So I guess that the dates listed in the current revision should be taken with a grain of salt. (Perhaps it would be worth updating - but I am aware that CMs have plenty of other things on their plates.)

Yeah, that post is due for an update.  Unfortunately, our original anticipated timeline didn't pan out.
